# Is there a way to only target one button in the React map?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**I am trying to make only one button in my React map method interactive. but when I click on one of them, they both react.  I would like to target only one button.Kindly assist**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Women() {
  const [womenShoes, setWomenShoes] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [addToCart, setAddToCart] = useState(true);

  const addItems = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setAddToCart(!addToCart);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://pacific-leaf-twig.glitch.me/women-shoes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setWomenShoes(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center gap-5 mt-5">
      {womenShoes.map((shoe, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="card mt-5" style={{ width: "25rem" }}>
          <img src={shoe.img} className="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="A shoe" />
          <div className="card-body d-flex">
            <div>
              <h5 className="card-title">{shoe.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{`Items Remaining ${shoe.itemsLeft}`}</p>
              <button onClick={addItems} className="btn btn-primary">
                {addToCart ? "Add to Cart" : "Remove from the Cart"}
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto align-self-center">
              <h4>{`$ ${shoe.price}`}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="counter">{`Items: ${count}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Women;
```

Comment: It's because the `addToCart` state applies to both buttons. It would be better to make it as a separate component with it's own state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a separate component for the `button` in order for it to have its own state. Here's a quick draft showing the changes:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

/* Button component with its own state. */
function AddButton({addItems}) {
  const [addToCart, setAddToCart] = useState(true);

  function addItem(){
    addItems();
    setAddToCart(!addToCart);
  }
  
  return (
    <button onClick={addItem} className="btn btn-primary">
      {addToCart ? "Add to Cart" : "Remove from the Cart"}
    </button>
  )
}

function Women() {
  const [womenShoes, setWomenShoes] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const addItems = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://pacific-leaf-twig.glitch.me/women-shoes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setWomenShoes(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center gap-5 mt-5">
      {womenShoes.map((shoe, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="card mt-5" style={{ width: "25rem" }}>
          <img src={shoe.img} className="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="A shoe" />
          <div className="card-body d-flex">
            <div>
              <h5 className="card-title">{shoe.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{`Items Remaining ${shoe.itemsLeft}`}</p>
              <AddButton addItems={addItems}/>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto align-self-center">
              <h4>{`$ ${shoe.price}`}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="counter">{`Items: ${count}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Women />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Wow, this also really helped me a lot Mr. Vasilis, I am a junior student developer and I'm very happy, I get to meet seniors like you who are willing to assist. I have been stuck at it for 2 days now. Thank you a lot. Let me go through the code again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the cart state separately. Following will keep an array of selected cart items. You can extend it to handle available counts and add multiple items of the same item.

```js
function Women() {
  const [womenShoes, setWomenShoes] = React.useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);

  const isSelectedItem = (itemId) => cart.indexOf(itemId) >= 0;

  const addItems = (itemId) => {
    setCart((prevItems) =>
      isSelectedItem(itemId)
        ? prevItems.filter((item) => item !== itemId)
        : [...prevItems, itemId]
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://pacific-leaf-twig.glitch.me/women-shoes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setWomenShoes(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center gap-5 mt-5">
      {womenShoes.map((shoe, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="card mt-5" style={{ width: "25rem" }}>
          <img src={shoe.img} className="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="A shoe" />
          <div className="card-body d-flex">
            <div>
              <h5 className="card-title">{shoe.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{`Items Remaining ${shoe.itemsLeft}`}</p>
              <button
                onClick={() => addItems(shoe.id)}
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                {!isSelectedItem(shoe.id)
                  ? "Add to Cart"
                  : "Remove from the Cart"}
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto align-self-center">
              <h4>{`$ ${shoe.price}`}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="counter">{`Items: ${cart.length}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Women />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: @Steve Zavi, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Amila. This was very helpful. I will have to go through the code several times to get the concept. Thank you again.